# how to make a component event that can change inner logic and parent's data at one shot

Tags: vuejs2

Here below is the simplified code:

```
var theButton = {
  props: ["toggle"],
  methods: {
    click: function (event) {
      event.target.style.backgroundColor = this.toggle ? "blue" : "gray";
    }
  },
  template: `
<button v-on:click="click" v-on:mouseup="$emit('change')">ABC</button> 
`
}

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    toggle: true
  },
  components: {
    "the-button": theButton
  },
  template: `
<div>
  <the-button v-bind:toggle="toggle" 
              v-on:change="toggle = !toggle"></the-button>
</div>
`
});
```

I create a component which only contain a button element. when clicking on it, the button background color and the bind data will be toggled.

As you can see, I set two events on the button. One `click` event for changing backgound color and one `mouseup` event for changing bind data. I don't bind two `click` events, or that will trigger an error.

**What I want to achieve** is creating a `click` event which can both change background color and set new data of the parent.

By the way, the bind data could be the prime data, such as String, Number or Boolean, overwirte those data directly can't change parent data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just move the code emitting the event into your click handler:

```
template: '<button v-on:click="click">ABC</button>'

...

methods: {
    click: function(event) {
      event.target.style.backgroundColor = this.toggle ? "blue" : "gray";
      this.$emit("change");
    }
  },
...
```

Here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-q-57405469-upepg?module=/src/main.js

Comment: Yes, it works. I tryed in this way but failed, I think something I miss. Many thanks.